# In CSS list-style-image displays the image to the left of the text, is it possible to shift the image to the right of the text?

Tags: html, css

In CSS list-style-image displays the image to the left of the text, is it possible to shift the image to the right of the text?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="headerNav">
 <ul>

    <li>Join Now</li>
    <li id="login">Log In</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#login {
    list-style-image:url('login_padlock.png');
}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using `list-style-image`, no. You could, however, assign a background image like this:

```
#login{
     background: url('login_padlock.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but not by using the list-style-image. What you need to do is use a background image aligned to the right. Something along the lines of this:

```
#headerNav li { list-style: none outside none; 
               padding-right: 25px; 
               background: url('login_padlock.png) 100% 0 no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score -2):

As I know it's not possible with a list.

You could make a table instead of a list, and put the image manually with a `<img>` tag in the last, separate column, with text-align set to right.

Comment: oh sry, i thought u'll add some more list items, and if u would put images on them to the right, they wouldn't be aligned vertical to each other.

guess my brain stoped working 4 bout 3 ours at work now X_X